# solr admin panel HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: solr

Am using digitalocean VPS I installed solr-5.5.0 
sudo service solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 1072 running on port 8983
{
  "solr_home":"/var/solr/data/",
  "version":"5.2.1 1684708 - shalin - 2015-06-10 23:20:13",
  "startTime":"2016-02-25T17:14:47.47Z",
  "uptime":"0 days, 8 hours, 39 minutes, 54 seconds",
  "memory":"92.1 MB (%18.8) of 490.7 MB"}

http://myip:8983/solr/
am getting this error on my screen.

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Powered by Jetty://

how to fix this error

Comment: This indicates some error during the startup process. Have you checked the logs?

Comment: How to check the Log?

Comment: Do a search for solr.log in your install dir and check that

Comment: ROR - 2016-02-25 17:30:42.515; [   ] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'gettingstarted1': Unable to create core [gettingstarted1] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/var/solr/data/gettingstarted1/conf'
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:661)

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says, you are missing the solrconfig.xml file in the conf folder of your core.

To get this file and all others, go to `{SOLR_DIST}/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs` and copy over the conf folder to `/var/solr/data/gettingstarted1` and restart solr.

This will fix the error.